# Where my heart [lays/lies]

Tags: grammar

There are many posts about lays/lies on the internet, but half of them contradict the others. It's an important letter - which is the proper form?

Comment: "Where my heart lays" is correct if your heart is a chicken.

Comment: @JimMack - Of course you are right. However there are more meaningful phrases possible, e.g.  "Where my heart lays its burden..." See my answer for some real-life examples.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is easily answered by consulting a dictionary. The verb 'to lie' is intransitive.  The verb 'to lay' is transitive. Therefore if you want to use the word 'lay' you must give it a direct object.

**Examples**

Hens lay **eggs**.

Please lay **the table**.

Now I lay **me** down to sleep.

A heart cannot lay anything. Therefore the answer is 'lie'.

**Definition**

> **lie**   verb
>   1.  ..
>   2. **be**, **remain**, or be kept in a specified state.
>
> https://www.google.co.uk/?gws_rd=ssl#q=lie+definition

**Answer**

Where my heart is = Where my heart remains = Where my heart lies.

---

P.S.

I lied when I said a heart can't lay anything. Here are some examples:

*And my heart lays **claim** to a mighty share Of desire and despair*
[Lyrics of the Middle Ages: An Anthology By James J. Wilhelm](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=rIOUgtk_DJgC&pg=PA203&dq=%22my%20heart%20lays%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CDUQ6AEwA2oVChMIz6KhmLTSyAIVQzIaCh1prQbF#v=onepage&q=%22my%20heart%20lays%22&f=false)

*My conscience is yelling a different kind of dream crystallizes and my heart lays **a pure pledge***
[Pangarap at hinagpis. Aida F. Santos](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=hppkAAAAMAAJ&q=%22my%20heart%20lays%22&dq=%22my%20heart%20lays%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CDsQ6AEwBGoVChMIz6KhmLTSyAIVQzIaCh1prQbF)

*My heart lays down **its load**.*
Literary genres in Tamil: [A. Ve Cuppiramaṇiyan̲, Shu Hikosaka, G. John Samuel](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=pra5AAAAIAAJ&q=%22my%20heart%20lays%22&dq=%22my%20heart%20lays%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CEMQ6AEwBmoVChMIz6KhmLTSyAIVQzIaCh1prQbF)

Of course, that fits in with my statement that 'to lay' is transitive.

Comment: Clear and didatic.  +1

Comment: Now only to look up the word "didactic". Thank you very much chasly from the UK!

Comment: @anon - I've added to my answer. I should have asked you in the first place for a complete sentence.  You could say, for example, "Where my heart lays its burden" and I just assumed that was not what you intended. Slapped wrist for me.